# Watch a file for change

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I want to watch any changes to a file xyz.txt and email me the entire file whenever there is a change. Is there One Liner (or a few lines shell script) for this?

**Update:**

```
# Check if my.cnf has been changed in the last 24 hours
# if yes, as in the following case, simply send the file
# if it has not been changed in the last 24 hours, do nothing.

# find /etc/ -name my.cnf -mtime 0
/etc/my.cnf

# cat /etc/my.cnf | mail shantanu@company.com
```

Now if someone can show how to bind these two lines in a shell script or in 1 command.

Comment: You could use [`fswatch`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) which is cross platform and straightforward `fswatch -o my_file | xargs -n1 -I{} my_program`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
find /etc/ -name my.cnf -mtime 0 -exec sh -c 'cat {} | mail -E -s "file changed" shantanu@company.com' \;
```

The `-E` option to `mail` prevents it from sending messages with empty bodies (as would be the case if `find` returns nothing and `cat` outputs nothing.

Comment: -E option does not seem to be available for my version of mail command

Comment: @shantanuo: Here is a question on Super User about [piping only when output is non-empty](http://superuser.com/q/210054/310).

Answer (score 25):

You could use `inotifywait`.  It waits for changes to a file, and then executes a command (e.g. something like `msmtp` in your case).

Answer (score 10):

You should look into [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) which can watch a file or directory and report changes.

Answer (score 3):

inotify-hookable is a perl script that is quite easy to use for this purpose. For example,

```
inotify-hookable -f /path/to/file -c "latexmk -pdf /path/to/file" &
inotify-hookable -f /path/to/file -c "cp /path/to/file /path/to/copy" &
```

-f for the file to watch
-c for the command to run

I had it watching a file in on a remote computer too, but inotify-hookable finished when the watched file was deleted prior to being updated.

I installed it from Debian. 
CPAN link: https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Inotify::Hookable

Answer (score 1):

As I've learnt from [another question over at superuser](https://superuser.com/a/665208/142948) (all credit due there):

> **entr** (https://github.com/eradman/entr)  provides a more friendly interface to inotify (and also supports *BSD & Mac OS X).

This watches a given file (or files) for changes and runs the command whenever (the instant) it changes. So you could do it like:

```
echo /etc/my.cnf | \
  entr sh -c 'cat /etc/my.cnf | mail -E -s "file changed" shantanu@company.com'
```

(PS. Credit to [Denis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228362/623519)'s answer for the mail command)

Comment: Sadly entrproject.org is now a spam site.

Comment: Try https://github.com/eradman/entr

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/ksh

ls -lt /usr/tip30/prtfile/asb270.prt|awk '{print $6$7$8}'|awk -F: '{print $1$2}'
 > /tmp/lastupdated.temp
read input_pid < /tmp/lastupdated.temp
echo "$input_pid"

while [ "$input_pid" -eq "`ls -lt /usr/tip30/prtfile/asb270.prt | awk '{print $6
$7$8}'|awk -F: '{print $1$2}'`" ]; do
   echo "file has not changed "
   sleep 30
done
echo "file changed `ls -lt /tmp/lastupdated.temp`"
rm /tmp/lastupdated.temp
```

Comment: Please format your code / provide some explanation why this solves the problem at hand.